# Can I use "reasonable" in place of "plausible" in the following context?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference, synonyms

> He says, "It is plausible if you put all these things together, you will get a good result."

Can I use "reasonable" instead of "plausible"? Are there any significant difference between them?

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary yet? What confused you about what you found there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [plausible explanation vs. reasonable explanation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/284671/plausible-explanation-vs-reasonable-explanation)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound correct if you use reasonable in the context you provided. Reasonable means something that makes sense and is rational and plausible means "seeming reasonable or probable". Seeming reasonable is not entirely reasonable. They cannot be used interchangeably.