# plausible explanation vs. reasonable explanation

Tags: word-usage

It seems to me that although "plausible explanation" shares the same meaning with "reasonable explanation", the latter is a bit more positive than the former. What is my reason at this? Compare: "a plausible man" and "a reasonable man"(or "a man of reason") - the latter is positive while the former is tending to be negative, because the former just appears to be honest and telling the truth even if they are not.

I am not absolutely sure. Though Oxford Dictionaries defines "plausible" as "reasonable" - which is statistically correct, one may feel quite differently when reading Cambridge Dictionary's definition "plausible: seeming likely to be true, or able to be believed" - which is much less positive than "reasonable."

**Is "plausible explanation" indeed a bit less positive than "reasonable explanation"?**

> plausible
> ​(of an excuse or explanation) reasonable and likely to be true
> Her story sounded perfectly plausible.
> The only **plausible explanation** is that he forgot.

Source: Oxford Dictionaries

Comment: I'd have thought this slight difference in nuance would be quite easy to recognise. Things which are ***reasonable*** really do make sense (so they're *very* likely to be true), whereas things which are ***plausible*** only ***appear to be reasonable***. So there's always a chance that the appearance is misleading, and the thing being referred to isn't *actually* even "reasonable", let alone *true*.

Comment: ...the first 4 dictionaries I checked for ***plausible*** (Cambridge, Merriam-Webster, Dictionary.com, Collins) all included "hedge" words such as ***seemingly, superficially, appearing, likely*** in definitions linking the meaning to concepts like ***reasonable***.

Comment: That answer is useful. But it doesn't fully answer my question, because Oxford Dictionaries is in my impression one of the most authoritative sources of English in the world. When Oxford directly defines "plausible" as "reasonable" as its first entry, it invites pondering. However, it appears to be safe to adopt the definition of "seemingly reasonable" if other dictionaries overwhelmingly define it that way.

Comment: The relevant definition from the *full* (subscription-only) OED is **4.a** - *Of an argument, an idea, a statement, etc.: **seeming** reasonable, probable, or truthful; convincing, believable; **(formerly) spec. having a false appearance of reason or veracity; specious.*** Does that not convince you?

Comment: Of course it does. Thank you.  But it also poses a new challenge or offers a caveat: Use our online free-version products at your own risk!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would rather close the older version as a duplicate of this one, which is better quality and has a positive score.

Answer (score 1):

I think the comparative strengths of "reasonable" and "plausible" can go either way.

There are reasonable explanations for the possible existence of life on Mars. They rely on actual observation and known science. But perhaps none that are plausible - actually likely to be true.

There are plausible explanations for the existence of ESP or UFOs but perhaps few that are reasonable.

Context is all.

Comment: I'm as certain as I can be that it makes no sense to say something is *plausible but not reasonable*. I can almost get my head around *reasonable but not plausible*, but in the final analysis I don't think that's really a credible / plausible / reasonable distinction either.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I almost agree with you. I struggled with my answer, and maybe shouldn't have bothered. That the measles vaccine causes autism was plausible when Lancet published the subsequently retracted study. Some people still believe that, but it's not reasonable to do so. But that argument involves time, and is about whether something I find unreasonable is plausible to someone else. Maybe I should just delete my answer.

Comment: Downvoter, your downvote is plausible but unfair (not reasonable)!

Comment: @LucianSava Thanks.